# Как перенести массив из скрипта в Excel?

Tags: vbscript, excel

Здравствуйте!

Я не имею большого опыта написания в VBScript. Сейчас пишу макрос для специализированной программки, в процедуре несколько циклов. Вначале я оглашаю размер формируемого массива, и в процессе расчётов он заполняется. Как вывести его в конце (после отработки макроса) в Ексель? Или какие команды надо написать, чтобы сам формировался (в процессе выполнения макроса) лист Екселя с заполняемыми столбцами?

Заранее спасибо! Очень надо научиться это делать.

Выглядит дело так:

```
r=setlocale("en-us") 
Sub

shag=0
Dim A(1000) B(1000) C(1000)

(команда на выполнение спец.программкой расчета, выполняется расчет)

А(shag)=(выполняется присвоение)
В(shag)=(выполняется присвоение)
С(shag)=(выполняется присвоение)

shag=shag+1

if
end if

for i=0 to максимальное число итераций

if (опускаю подробности)
end if

(команда на выполнение спец.программкой расчета, выполняется расчет)

А(shag)=(выполняется присвоение)
В(shag)=(выполняется присвоение)
С(shag)=(выполняется присвоение)

shag=shag+1

next

if (опускаю подробности)
end if

for j=0 to максимальное число итераций
if
end if

(команда на выполнение спец.программкой расчета, выполняется расчет)

А(shag)=(выполняется присвоение)
В(shag)=(выполняется присвоение)
С(shag)=(выполняется присвоение)

shag=shag+1

next

End Sub
```

Всё, собственно. Хочется получить в Екселе эти три столбца (или в виде строк), заполненные A, B и C.

Я написала для вывода следующее:

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

xlApp.Application.Visible = True

for shag=1 to 1000
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 1).Value = A(shag)
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 2).Value = B(shag)
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 3).Value = C(shag)
shag=shag+1
next

xlSheet.SaveAs "C:\TEST.XLS"
```

Но в результате выскакивает лист Екселя пустой, с табличкой об ошибке. Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

xlApp.Application.Visible = True

dim a(2)
dim b(2)
dim c(2)

a(1) = 1
a(2) = 1
b(1) = a(2) + a(1)
b(2) = b(1) + a(2)
c(1) = b(2) + b(1)
c(2) = c(1) + b(2)

for shag=1 to 2
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 1).Value = A(shag)
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 2).Value = B(shag)
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 3).Value = C(shag)
next
```

Comment: Так будет правильнее.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, зачем в цикле for в конце делать инкремент shag? Я не спец по VBScript, но во всех языках, что я использовал, самому инкремент ставить не надо. Во-вторых, напиши текст ошибки, которую выдаёт Excel. Ошибка, возможно, заключается в том, что свойство переменной xlSheet - Cells строковая переменная, и ей нельзя присваивать инт.

Comment: спасибо за совет. shag я пишу т.к. он должен же заполнить всю 1000 строк (я полагаю, что он А В и С расположит по столбцам) - и чтобы массив заполнялся я и пишу for next для каждого шага shag (строка), ну могу заменить на i ...

а ошибку выдаёт дословно следующую:
Type mismatch: "A"

Comment: Но, может, я что-то не так поняла, я тоже не очень в VBScript, - потому и спрашиваю))... если нетрудно, напиши мне (`conrl c`), как считаешь вывод массива `Dim` должен выглядеть?

Comment: Грустно... неужели никто не знает ответ?
Мне казалось этот перенос должен быть элементрен и прост...