# Почему лист Excel пустой?

Tags: vbscript, vba, excel, visual-basic

> Сделано вопросом из комментария в теме: [Как перенести массив из скрипта в Ecxel?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/59477/) @ХэшКод

Я написала для вывода следующее:

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

xlApp.Application.Visible = True

for shag=1 to 1000
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 1).Value = A(shag)
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 2).Value = B(shag)
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 3).Value = C(shag)
        shag=shag+1
next

xlSheet.SaveAs "C:\TEST.XLS"
```

Но в результате выскакивает лист Екселя пустой! - С табличкой об ошибке... что не так? (((

Answer (score 1):

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

xlApp.Application.Visible = True

dim a(2)
dim b(2)
dim c(2)

a(1) = 1
a(2) = 1
b(1) = a(2) + a(1)
b(2) = b(1) + a(2)
c(1) = b(2) + b(1)
c(2) = c(1) + b(2)

for shag=1 to 2
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 1).Value = A(shag)
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 2).Value = B(shag)
xlSheet.Cells(shag, 3).Value = C(shag)
next
```